# prevent external medium boot on my toshiba l50 laptop

Tags: boot, usb, security, toshiba-laptop

I need to restrict an employee to use the company's laptop software, I am trying to prevent booting the laptop from external usb devices, which seems impossible to me until now, how can I do this ??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the specifics of the BIOS settings, but if it is flexible enough, then you would do the following in the BIOS settings:

- Modify the  boot order to make sure the internal drive is first
- Disable booting other devices
- Create system password to protect the BIOS

Comment: Thank you for your contribution but I tried those options already and non has worked.

Comment: Sorry it hasn't worked. That is the answer, none the less. Either you haven't set the options correctly, or the laptop doesn't have the feature you're looking for. But, that would be a surprise because most at least do have that. However, some laptops are so cheap the manufacturer has given next to no options in the BIOS. Any business class laptop would support this though. Please specify the exact model of your laptop and I'll try to look it up for you.